# how fast is disk acces on iphone and android to write/update data

Tags: android, ios, iphone, hardware

In my app, I am storing the user's data in json on their phones. I am trying to decide on how often should I be updating the data on the phone. Let me give an example-
user had several tasks to do, and in each task, the user clicks on a button several number of times to update a number to their needs. This "number" is what's important to stay persistent when the user starts the app next time in case he quits the app.

Now if the user is clicking the button 20 times for example (in quick succession - like couple seconds), should I update the json after every click? As in, is it a fast enough operation? Or should I wait for like 5 seconds after a user had clicked the button to actually update all data at once?

I know this depends upon the implementation of writing file to disk and a few other operation - lets assume it's implemented very well and we are writing only a page long json. Is the disk on phones now a days fast enough to write to disk in such speeds? 
From my testing on an iphone5, it seems VERY VERY fast to do such operations. But I am not sure if this is always the case or just my test scenario.
The persistance of the user's number is VERY important in my app and I need to be as safe and careful as possible to not lose it.

Comment: phones don't have disk. they have flash memory and it has a limited lifespan based on the number of writes. while writing to it is required and unavoidable, you should NOT be dumping zillions of trivial updates.

Comment: @MarcB yeah, i used disk in a very lazy way. good point! I never thought of it from the lifespan point of view. though, I am pretty sure the lifespan of flash is a lot more than the duration for which a person even keeps their phones now a days (2-3 years, lesser if they have money to upgrade or if they break their phones/put it in the washing machine/crack screen and need to replace). I don't think the lifespan really matters now a days. any opinion on the speed of access? What are the typical write speeds on flash memory of phones? for regular computers -ssd's range in 3-600megs/sec? same?

Comment: desktop/server-class SSDs will have multiple chips in a kind of RAID setup for extra speed. since a phone's space is at a premium, it'll have very much fewer flash chips and will never achieve SSD-grade speeds.

Comment: ok cool. Are there apps for iphone you know of to find out the speeds? I know apple doesn't officially release their specs (I could be wrong). I will look for that

Comment: I have run across reviews that benchmarked read/writes on some devices, but that was quite a while ago.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion 20 updates in few seconds isn't so much time consuming. More time will take for example building complicated JSON string rather than saving it. But as @Marc B mentioned maybe a better solution will be saving bigger amount of data for example on onDestroy or other "postExecute" method. I believe it will be simpler solution. If you want to store only number of clicks its rather simple to count and save at the end. If not please give as more details

Comment: my scenario is that the user can click on the button lke 20 times in couple seconds. Then they might decide to go to another screen. But the user might decide to come back to the last screen to click the button again (to inc or dec it). At every moment, I need to have the clicks recorded in the flash memory. That's why, I am so curious about the speeds.

Comment: So you can simply use global variables. If you need to access them in several activities you can extend Application class http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: ah totally forgot about extending the app class! sweet, that helps! Thanks and accepted!